# A nicer way of remapping the model attribute name with ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The backend supplies an attribute called `content` which clashes with the controller `content`, so I'm remapping it:

```
App.Webinar = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string')
});

/**
 * Remap content -> body so it doesn't clash with the controller.
 */
App.EventSerializer = DS.DjangoRESTSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function(type, hash, prop) {
    hash.body = hash.content;
    delete hash.content;
    return hash;
  },
  serialize: function(record, options) {
    var json = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    json.content = json.body;
    delete json.body;
    return json;
  }
});
```

Is there a nicer way of doing this with ember-data?